# Distance calculation in turtle gives nothing

Tags: python, distance, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to calculate the distance the turtle has traveled from the center point, but it's not giving me anything when I run it:

```
import math
import turtle
import random

# Starter Code
def randomTurtle():

    for count in range(10):
        choice = random.randint(1,2)
        if (choice==1):
            turtle.forward(random.randint(5, 50))
        elif(choice==2):
            turtle.right(random.randint(1,359))

randomTurtle()
    
def calculateDistance(x,y):

    dist = math.sqrt((0 - x)**2 + (0 - y)**2)
    print(dist)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Also, create a [mcve] and include that (properly formatted as code) in your question. Further, "not giving me anything" isn't really a good description of what you get, nor does it say what you expected and why.

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then come back and edit the question. Can you please format your question so all the code is in code blocks. Also what have you tried? What do you want your output to be? How are you calling `calculateDistance`?

Comment: it's seems that you're not calling `calculateDistance` you can do it by `calculateDistance(*turtle.position())` or first define `x, y = turtle.position()`and then call `calculateDistance(x,y)` I've tried the code and it works fine..

Comment: I'm trying to use the distance formula to calculate the distance turtle has travel using `def calculateDistance`, I tried using `x, y = turtle.position()` and call `calculateDistance(x,y)` at first but it keep saying x and y is not define, how do use the random turtle position as  (x,y)  and plug it into the `Def calculateDistance` . So basically if 'def RandomTurtle' stop at (5,50), x=5, y= 50 then those 2 values would go plug into the equation and the answer should be 50.249378

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rework of your code using turtle's own `distance()` method, you should be able to substitute your own distance formula if desired:

```
import turtle
from random import choice, randint

def randomTurtle():
    for _ in range(10):
        if choice([True, False]):
            turtle.dot(3, 'red')  # illustrate choices
            turtle.forward(randint(5, 50))
        else:
            turtle.right(randint(1, 359))

def calculateDistance():
    print(turtle.distance((0, 0)))

randomTurtle()
calculateDistance()

turtle.done()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
79.31702982354314
```

[image]